# Add the Options List to the email template when sharing Wishlist

Tags: magento-1.7, custom-options, email-templates, wishlist

I have been looking into adding the the custom options list (located in app/design/frontend/CUSTOMTEMPLATE/default/template/wishlist/options_list.phtml) in the email that is sent when sharing the wishlist via email.

I have also found the thread about the function being used (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821118/finding-a-magento-method-definition-specifically-getoptionlist) but I do not understand it.

I tried copy and pasting the code in options_list.phtml into the wishlist/email/items.phtml file, but obviously that does not work. I literally just need to list out the custom options that were saved to the wishlist items, inside the email that is sent when sharing.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Which part did you not understand? As it says in the answer: "Extend or rewrite the Mage_Wishlist_Block_Customer_Wishlist_Item_Options" > seems you did not do that?